# How to handle methods that take arguments in es6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

Well, I am kinda surprised that I had to ask a question about this but most examples provide a getter and setter but I have not seems a functions that takes parameters in es6 classes.

Given the following example from MDN web docs.

```
class Rectangle {


constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

console.log(square.area);
```

How can I add a method that takes n amount of arguments and returns something.

Example in old js

```
var doSomething = function(theThing) {
    // process something 
    return theThingProcessed;
}
```

Comment: `calcArea` is defined as `calcArea() { … }` and called as `this.calcArea()`. If you wanted a function `foo` to take an argument and be called as `this.foo(arg)`, can you guess what the syntax would be?

Comment: It's identical to regular function declarations for declaring and using arguments.

Comment: Read the question again. @Ryan

Comment: @Beto: Why, did you change something?

Answer (score 0):

Like you did in the constructor except with a name?

```
class Rectangle {


constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

  doSomething(theThing,theThing2,...n){
    //process something


    return theThingProcessed;
  }
}

const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
square.doSomething(theThing);
console.log(square.area);
```